# I want to show contacts of an account

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to show contacts of an account, for that I have created LWC, I am calling Apex method here and I want to show all contacts of an account using data table, but data is not showing in the UI.
I am using custom label to pass account to Apex class.
please help me to achieve this
below is my code

JS Code:

```js
const columns = [    
    { label: "Name", fieldName: "Name" },   
    { label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone"},
    { label: "Email", fieldName: "Email"}
];
@track contactsList =[];

@wire(GetContacts,{AccountId:this.AccountId}) 
WireContactRecords({error, data}){
    console.log('Entering WireContactRecords');
    console.log('Entering WireContactRecords===='+this.AccountId);
    if(data){
        console.log('data*********+'+JSON.stringify(data))
        this.contactsList = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    }else{
        this.error = error;
        this.contactsList = undefined;
    }
}
```

Apex class

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static Contact GetContacts(String AccountId){
        String query = 'SELECT Name,Phone,Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: AccountId';
        return Database.query( query );
}
```

HTML CODE

```html
 <lightning-datatable
                                    
     data={contactsList}
      columns={columns}
      key-field="id"
      hide-checkbox-column>
 </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to pass the value of a property defined in the JS class to a wired function is: `@wire(functionName, { param: '$propertyName' })`

Therefore, assuming that your class has an `AccountId` property, you have to change

```
@wire(GetContacts,{AccountId:this.AccountId})
```

to

```
@wire(GetContacts,{AccountId: '$AccountId'})
```

Moreover in the HTML you can use only property defined in your JS class, so if `columns` is defined only outside it, you should provide a getter:

```
get columns() {
    return columns;
}
```

Comment: I tried exact syntax, but that did not work. I am trying to pass account Id from custom labels which i have stored

Comment: @user97539 Could you please edit your question adding the whole JS file?